# How to make a fluid anchor scrolling in a select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't make a fluid scrolling with a select option element, only with a link. Can anyone help me?

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4bHG2/)!

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4bHG2/1/)

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
         $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(this.value).offset().top
                }, 1000);
    });
```

And remove onchange inline attribute

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what i want is a fluid scrolling with a select>option like a link how you can see in my jsfiddle demo

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " a select>option like a link" You want the page to be redirected and then fluid animation on new page?

Comment: How you can see here> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4bHG2/) - I have make two anchor links. One with a <a> element and one with a select>option element. The anchor with a <a> element have a fluid scrolling, how you can see when you click that. But, the option element can't make the same. I want a help for make a fluid anchor scrolling when a click on option element. Understand?

Comment: @user3130064 But isn't it exactly what does my posted answer??? http://jsfiddle.net/4bHG2/1/  If you select an option, then page scroll... If not what you expect, please improve your question, understand?!

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this! I'm still a noob in javascript and jquery and only with your jsfiddle demo i have understand! Is exactly this! Thanks you so much!